# How can subclass pointers strictly equal parent class pointers?

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers

I was writing an operator== between two kinds of smart pointer and thought I should run a quick sanity check. I'm suprised by the result...

In the snippet below how is it that all variants of f and b end up with the same value?

```
struct Foo {
    int x;
};

struct Bar : public Foo {
    int y;
};

#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    Bar bar;

    Foo * f = &bar;
    Bar * b = &bar;
    std :: cout << f << " " << b << " " << (f == b) << "\n";

    void * fv = f;
    void * bv = b;
    std :: cout << fv << " " << bv << " " << (fv == bv) << "\n";

    int fi = reinterpret_cast <int> (f);
    int bi = reinterpret_cast <int> (b);
    std :: cout << fi << " " << bi << " " << (fi == bi) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Incidentally, the original aim was to verify that the expression (f==b) is equivalent to (f==(Foo*)b) -- I need this implicit conversion so that it behaves properly with templates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

About the only time that a base class object won't have the same address as its subclass object is when multiple inheritance is involved.

In the above example memory probably looks like this:

```
                               / --------- \
                              /  | x     |  > This is the Foo portion of bar
This is the whole Bar object <   --------- /  
                              \  | y     |  
                               \ ---------
```

Both views of the object have the same starting point, so a pointer to either view will have the same value.

In multiple inheritance, things get more complicated.  Say you have:

```
struct Foo1{ int x; };
struct Foo2{ int y; };
struct Bar : public Foo1, public Foo2 { int z; };
Bar bar;
```

Now the memory will have to be laid out something like this:

```
                                / --------- \
                               /  | x     |  > This is the Foo1 portion of bar
                              /   --------- / \ 
This is the whole Bar object <    | y     |    > This is the Foo2 portion of bar  
                              \   ---------   /
                               \  | z     |  
                                \ ---------
```

So `&bar` and `(Foo1*)&bar` will have the same value, while `(Foo2*)&bar` will have a different value, since it the `Foo2` portion of the object starts at a higher address.

Comment: I have also found that pointers between parent and child classes will differ when `virtual` inheritance is used

Answer (score 2):

This is the typical memory layout you will end up with:

```
Bar starts   Foo starts    x starts / ends  Foo ends   y starts / ends  Bar ends
|            |             |             |         |   |             |         |
```

Sice there is nothing between Bar start and Foo start, the offset of Foo can be zero, therefore the pointers for Bar, Foo and x might be identical.

Comment: @Noah OK, what exactly does prevent this from happening?

Comment: You might actually be right, it's just confusing so I can't really tell.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, the first part of a derived class is its parent.  Thus a pointer to derived and pointer to base on the same object are often equal.  However, this changes with multiple inheritance.  In the case of MI, generally speaking, the first pat of a derived class it its *parents* in some possibly arbitrary order (don't know and doesn't matter for this).  Thus if you have a pointer to derived, a pointer to base1, and a pointer to base2, with derived multiply inheriting from both, the three pointers will probably not all be equal; two might be.

The void* don't have to be the same but generally will be.

The reinterpret_cast to int is the same because the values of the pointers are the same.

Comment: -1 `static_cast` to `void*` doesn't change pointer value as is implied by the answer

Answer (score 0):

`operator==()` is simply assessing whether `f` and `b` are pointing to the same thing, which in this case they are.

Answer (score 0):

Most compilers layout parent class object at the beginning of the child class object, so the addresses are the same, no surprises here.

Answer (score 0):

You have essentially overlaid `f` and `b` onto the same memory location (`&bar`). So actually, I'm confused as to how you would ever expect them to be different.